# how to display json response in view under specific field in laravel?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I am returning a JSON response from my controller after validation. Now am looking for a way to display this response on each specific field with an error like in this image:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfm6p.png)

I have tried converting the JSON to array then displaying but with this method I can't display on specific error fields

```
$file = request()->file('letter_of_request');
$allowed = ['pdf'];
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed)){
    return response([
        'errors'=>[
            'letter_of_request'=>'Please upload a valid file (Upload a file with extension .pdf)'
        ]
    ],422);
}
```

I want to be able to display those errors on the fields with errors only.

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: return response(json_encode($yourArray), ResponseStatus);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel Form [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) for your validations

```
php artisan make:request LetterCreateRequest
```

then set the rules on the App\Http\Request\LetterCreateRequest

```
public function authorize()
{
   return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'letter_of_request' => 'required|mimes:pdf',
    ];
}
```